# Small World network on a square grid

Tags: graphs-and-networks, grid-layouts, topology

My aim is to generate a 2D Small World network on a square grid. i.e. 20x20.
With a probability of 5%, one node rewires from an adjacent node to a random node of the grid, allowing some long distance edges. Yet, the grid topology should be fixed. More specifically, the vertices sould be fixed, only the edges may be replaced, maintaining an average degree of <4>. All my tries ended up in the breaking of the grid topology.
Unfortunately, the WattStrogatzGraphDistribution does not help as well,as it is not embedded on a lattice.

The result should somewhat look like this:
[image: 2D Small World on a Grid]

(Source: Biondo et al. (2013) - Reducing Financial Avalanches By Random Investments , Phys. Rev. E 88, 062814)

The colored nodes are not from importance.
The question might be helpful for others,too, who try to implement a certain type of network topology on a lattice. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) package has the `IGRewire` function which will randomly rewire edges while keeping the degree sequence. There's also `IGRewireEdges` which keeps the total number of edges (thus also the average degree), but it does not preserve the degree sequence.  Take a look.  These can be implemented in pure Mathematica too, but I would be lazy to do that ;-) `GridGraph` will be useful too.

Comment: `g = GridGraph[{20, 20}]; 
EdgeAdd[EdgeDelete[g, #], 
   Thread[UndirectedEdge[#[[All, 1]], 
     RandomChoice[VertexList@g, Length@#]]]] &@
 Pick[EdgeList@g, 
  RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.05], Length@EdgeList@g], 1]`?

Comment: Marginal to your question, but it's good to not that if you start with the grid shown here, the rewired networks will not have the small world property as originally defined by Watts and Strogatz because a simple lattice like this does not have a high clustering coefficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quick summary**

- The [IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) has several functions to help with this (`IGRewireEdges`).
- The rewired network will not have the small world property unless the starting grid connects at least second neighbours as well.  IGraph/M has a function to generate such a starting grid (`IGMakeLattice`).

---

#### Easiest is to use IGraph/M!

While this can be implemented in pure Mathematica, it is even easier with [the IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM).

```
<< IGraphM`
```

We start with a grid graph:

```
g = GridGraph[{30, 30}];
coords = GraphEmbedding[g];
```

`IGRewireEdges` will rewire each edge with probability *p*, preserving the total number of edges.

```
?IGRewireEdges
```

> IGRewireEdges[graph, p] rewires each edge of the graph with probability p.

```
Graph[IGRewireEdges[g, 0.1], VertexCoordinates -> coords]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can control whether the creation of self loops or multi-edges is allowed:

```
Options[IGRewireEdges]
(* {SelfLoops -> False, "MultipleEdges" -> False} *)
```

`IGRewire` will rewire in such a way as to preserve the degree of each vertex.  We can specify the number of rewiring trials (not all of which may succeed).

```
?IGRewire
```

> IGRewire[graph, n] attempts to rewire the edges of graph n times while preserving its degree sequence.

```
Graph[IGRewire[g, 100], VertexCoordinates -> coords]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can control whether the creation of self loops is allowed:

```
Options[IGRewire]
(* {SelfLoops -> False} *)
```

---

Need for this functionality was one of the reasons why I wrote IGraph/M.  While it can be implemented in Mathematica, that is simply not fast enough for many implemented.

---

#### What is a "small-world" network?

Originally ([Watts & Strogatz](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v393/n6684/full/393440a0.html)) a "small world" property of the network referred to having

1. A short average shortest path length
2. A high clustering coefficient

A random graph has (1) but not (2). 
A graph like in the figure below  has (2) but not (1):

[image]

So they made something "inbetween" by starting with this regular lattice where *every 2nd neighbour* is connected and rewiring edges to make it more random, achieving *both* properties at the same time.

[image]

**Does your network have the small world property?**  No, because a simple grid graph does not have a high clustering coefficient.

```
N@GlobalClusteringCoefficient@GridGraph[{30, 30}]

(* 0. *)
```

Nor does a cycle graph, which is a periodic 1D grid graph with only first neighbours connected.  We need at least every second neighbour connected, like this:

```
g = IGMakeLattice[{10}, Radius -> 2, Periodic -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N@GlobalClusteringCoefficient[g]
(* 0.5 *)
```

IGraph/M's grid graph generator helps here because it has the `Radius` option to connect $n^\text{th}$ neighbours.  We can also do it for 2D:

```
g = IGMakeLattice[{20, 20}, Radius -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's check the clustering and average shortest path length before rewiring ...

```
N@GlobalClusteringCoefficient[g]
(* 0.468933 *)

IGAveragePathLength[g]
(* 6.91729 *)
```

... and after rewiring:

```
g2 = IGRewireEdges[g, 0.03];

N@GlobalClusteringCoefficient[g2]
(* 0.390251 *)

IGAveragePathLength[g2]
(* 3.64128 *)
```

The clustering coefficient is reduced somewhat, but not significantly.  The average path length is however cut in half.

**We see that to get the small world property we must start with a lattice where at least second neighbours are connected!**

Comment: The IGraph tool looks very convincing! I'm going to give it a try for sure. 
Especially, since there is no global clusering coefficient involved in mathematica's gridgraph. The "problem" with the declining average path length is not really a problem, as it is an arbitrary setting, and we can keep the average path length low by considering smaller rewiring probabilities, to be in line with i.e. real world social network topologies. So, thanks for your Help! :)

Comment: Sorry, i accidentally posted  the comment before it was ready.

Comment: @ResidentStiefel Let me know if you have any trouble with IGraph/M!  What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using 64-Bit Windows10, and it works just fine!

Comment: @Szabolcs Excellent answer! Question about the rewiring: given that we have the vertex coords and can calculate the Euclidean dist between pairs of nodes, could we rewire edges locally? (i.e. similar to a nearest neighbour approach, considering, 1st,2nd, 3rd.. furthest neighbours).

Comment: @user929304 We could, but that would have to be implemented fro scratch. My expectation is that if the rewiring is strictly local, then the rewiring would not be able to decrease the mean shortest path length by much (or rather that there would be a limit on how much it can be reduced). Thus, the model you propose may not be able to produce networks with the small-world property (i.e. short paths, high clustering).

Comment: @user929304 I saw you got an answer there. Is that sufficient or are you still looking for somethign?

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for getting back to me! that answer is really neat and to the point. However, it does not (yet) address how one could probabilistically assign edges to nearest neighbours, and the approach is not straightforwardly extensible to graphs not necessarily embedded in *unit* squares (speaking of which, I don't know how to extract area of a given embedding). I am trying this stacking for larger graphs (1000 nodes each) and to verify how and which edges have been assigned is quite tedious as visually one cannot tell much. Any additional inputs you might have would be really cool!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment. Dr.belisarius' answer, given in comment to the question, looks promising, but it can produce loops, Is this admissible?

```
SeedRandom[1];
With[{g = GridGraph[{20, 20}]}, 
  EdgeAdd[
    EdgeDelete[g, #], 
    Thread[UndirectedEdge[#[[All, 1]], RandomChoice[VertexList @ g, Length @ #]]]]& @
      Pick[
        EdgeList @ g, 
        RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.05], Length@EdgeList@g], 1]]
```

[image: graph]